# Pentaho: Insert a set of dynamic records into a database

Tags: insert, pentaho, kettle, pdi

Using Pentaho, I would like to SELECT a number of records from a database and INSERT them into another one. I have no problem with the first part and using `Input Table` step, I have selected my desired records. But I have no idea about how to develop a step in Pentaho that takes care of inserting these records into the second database. Can anyone please guide me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic records we can easily insert in to another database. By using parameters.

=> Database join step:- Write one sql like based on your requirement.
 Eg:- select * from table_name where column_name = ?

=> Table output step:- Here create another database connection. And then select map the fields.

Note:- You can't use table input step for dynamics record (i.e you can't write parameter based sql's).

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful and I used "Table Output" to insert data in database and now it works. However, for selecting data from another database "Table Input" worked and I don't have any problem with that part.

Comment: I think you are changing database connection dynamically? other wise how to get dynamic record.